# RPI 3 hangs on HDMI out but can SSH fine

Tags: pi-3, boot, ssh

I have a RPI 3 that I bought a year ago, and I have only used the HDMI out 3 times. After I worked on setting it up, I unplugged the HDMI until today. It gets through the text on the boot up, but never goes to the GUI.

But I can SSH into a command prompt with putty. And the RPI ends up on a fsck command on the main partition. And it always ends up fixing a dirty bit "0x41".

Even Xtightvnc runs and I can use VNC viewer to make a virtual screen. I really want the HDMI output back working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using the `startx` command?

Comment: there is no command prompt to write startx

Comment: You can't have bought a RPI 3 B+ a year ago as it only came out last month.  You might want to correct that ...

Answer (score 1):

SSH to raspberry pi using your credentials and type `sudo raspi-config`

This command will open up the raspberry pi configuration.

In this configuration screen, look for the option

> enable boot to Desktop/Scratch.

In the Next screen, choose

> Desktop Login as user 'Pi' at the graphical desktop

You'll be asked to reboot afterwards. And on the next boot, you will be logged in to LXDE desktop environment. And you can enjoy the GUI experience with raspberry pi.

Comment: please note the names of options like `enable boot to ...` are different on current versions of raspbian, but the function is still the same. For example, in current versions of raspbian, you'd go to `boot options` ->   `desktop / CLI` -> `Desktop`.

Comment: OK, thank you. I've crossed checked the names and new ones are correctly mentioned by you.